# Swiftmail error: fork failed - Cannot allocate memory

Tags: php, swiftmailer

Im sending 5k email through swiftmail (5.0.1) using the sendmail method:

```
$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -t');
```

I used to have no problems but receantly im getting this errors:

```
Warning: proc_open() [function.proc-open]: fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in /swmailer501/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 285

Warning: stream_set_blocking(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /swmailer501/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 286

Warning: stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /swmailer501/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 287

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /swmailer501/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 108

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /swmailer501/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 109

Warning: proc_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /swmailer501/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 110
```

I try different configurations and sending methods but no success, any ideas?

Comment: have your changed something? Updated swiftmail? Updated PHP? I believe software don't break themselves..

Answer (score 0):

You are either legitimately running out of system memory or you have bad ram.

I am not familiar with Swift_SendmailTransport, but from your error it appears to be spawning processess, which are failing to start due to lack of memory.

If it is the prior you might want to try running fewer at once or add more ram to your machine.